# Execute own command in listing

Tags: macros, listings

I create an own command like this

```
\newcommand{\hostname}{this.is.my.hostname}
```

Now I want to use this command in normal text (no problem) and inside of a listing

```
Nun kann die Funktionsweise überprüft werden:

\begin{lstlisting}[language=BashGriduser]
su -l griduser
globus-url-copy gsiftp://\hostname:2811/home/share/test file:///home/share/test2
\end{lstlisting}
```

In the text, the command is executed without any problems. Inside the listing it is printed as `\hostname`. How can I execute this inside the listing or pass this as parameter or something like that.

Comment: You need to escape to normal TeX code to process the macro. See the `listings` manual for how to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can "escape" things as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{%
  escapeinside={(*}{*)},%
}
\newcommand\foo{Bar}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
  Text (*\foo*)
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Enclose macros you want tex to actually read inside some "escaping" mechanism defined by `escapeinside`

Comment: awkwardly, this won't work if the command `\foo` contains macros that you want set verbatim... I guess you'd need to use expansion magic to get around that